# Wrap macro with variable number of arguments

Tags: c, arguments, variadic-functions, variadic-macros

I need to wrap a macro so that it can be accessed with a function.
The macro is defined like:

```
#define gDbgLog(fmt,...)  dbgLog(g_pdbg,MODULE_NAME,__FUNCTION__,fmt,##__VA_ARGS__)
```

and I've attempted to wrap it up like:

```
void pMonDbgLog(char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,fmt);
    gDbgLog(fmt,args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

while `fmt` seems to come through fine, the arguments (int) seem to get clobbered up. I call it like:

```
int x = 51144;
pMonDbgLog("some text %d",x);
```

and what I get is **"some text 642129608"** while calling the macro directly like `DbgLog("some text %d",x);` works fine. Why is this?

`dbgLog()` wraps `vsnprintf()` to generate the output.

Comment: It looks like for your example usage you could call the macro directly, i.e. `gDbgLog("some text %d",x);`. Why do you think you need a function wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wrap macro with variable number of arguments

It simply is not possible to "expand" a `valist` to a variable number of arguments and pass those to a variadic functions on run-time, at least not with any additional helpers (which are not part of C and are not portable and might not be available for you implementation/platform).

`gDbgLog()` expects getting *each* argument passed *separately*:

```
gDbgLog("%s %d", "hello, world", 42);
```

What the code you show does instead is passing exactly *one* parameter as the `__VA_ARGS__` part, namely the value of `valist`.

```
gDbgLog(fmt,args);
```

---

How to solve this?

> dbgLog() wraps vsnprintf() to generate the output.

So just drop `gDbgLog()` and call `vsnprintf()` from `pMonDbgLog()` directly passing the `valist` as initialised by the code snippet you show.